# How to loop through a list and create a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

Thank you in advance.

I have a list of file paths from list.files. I am attempting to call each file and standardise the number of columns so that I can then bind each file into one large DF.

With Team being the list here is my code (note Add_X_Col is a function to standardise the number of columns):

```
x1<-read.csv(Team[1],row.names=1) #Reads the csv from the first file path
y<-ncol(x1) #creates object with number of columns
#If statement to standarise number of columns so can bind
if (y=="37"){ 
  x1<-Add_5_Col(x1)
} else if (y=="38"){
  x1<-Add_4_Col(x1)
} else if (y=="39"){
  x1<-Add_3_Col(x1)
} 
Team_Split<-x1 #Creates a new DF called Team_Split 
Team<-Team[-1];#Removes the file path from the list
```

Second Portion - I am having to repeat this ~275 times for all files in the directed file path

```
x1<-read.csv(Team[1],row.names=1) #Reads the csv from the first file path
y<-ncol(x1) #creates object with number of columns
#If statement to standarise number of columns so can bind
if (y=="37"){ 
  x1<-Add_5_Col(x1)
} else if (y=="38"){
  x1<-Add_4_Col(x1)
} else if (y=="39"){
  x1<-Add_3_Col(x1)
} 
Team_Split<-rbind(Team_Split,x1) #Binds to already made Team_Split DF 
Team<-Team[-1];
```

My intended output would be a large dataframe, reading  each file in the file path as a dataframe and binding them together.

I am unfamiliar with looping and using the apply package; I've attempted to understand them to use them here but to no avail! Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT, as requested.

```
Add_3_Col <- function(x){
  names(x1)[names(x1) == "X60"] <- "X60.1"
  x1$X60<- 0
  x1$X105<- 0
  x1$X110<- 0
  x1<-x1[c(1:12,40,13:24,41,42,25:39)]
  return(x1)
}
Add_5_Col <- function(x){
  names(x1)[names(x1) == "X55"] <- "X55.1"
  names(x1)[names(x1) == "X60"] <- "X60.1"
  x1$X55<- 0
  x1$X60<- 0
  x1$X100<- 0
  x1$X105<- 0
  x1$X110<- 0
  x1<-x1[c(1:11,38,39,12:22,40,41,42,23:37)] #re-arrnages to put the columns in the correct place.
  return(x1)
}
Add_4_Col <- function(x){
  names(x1)[names(x1) == "X55"] <- "X55.1"
  names(x1)[names(x1) == "X60"] <- "X60.1"
  x1$X55<- 0
  x1$X60<- 0
  x1$X105<- 0
  x1$X110<- 0
  x1<-x1[c(1:11,39,40,12:23,41,42,24:38)]
  return(x1)
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code for the `ADD_X_COLS` functions?

Comment: @iamericfletcher See edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me with a bunch of CSV files with mock data.

```
Team <- list.files("c:\\Test\\Teams\\", full.names=TRUE)

Team_Split <- data.frame()
print(Team)

for (Team_File in Team) {
  xl <-
    read.csv(Team_File) #Reads the csv from the first file path
  y <- ncol(x1) #creates object with number of columns
  #If statement to standarise number of columns so can bind
  if (y == "37") {
    x1 <- Add_5_Col(x1)
  } else if (y == "38") {
    x1 <- Add_4_Col(x1)
  } else if (y == "39") {
    x1 <- Add_3_Col(x1)
  }
  # Sets Team_Split to xl if it's the first set of data 
  # or binds Team_Split and xl
  print(xl)
  
  if (nrow(Team_Split) == 0) {
    Team_Split <- xl 
  } else {
    Team_Split <- rbind(Team_Split, xl)
  }
}

print(Team_Split)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @norie. Your suggestion creates an output of the list of files names/paths. See my edit of original post to see my intended output.

Comment: There were some typos in my answer but they would cause errors rather than the behaviour you describe. I've updated my code to fix the typos

Comment: I still believe there are some typo's i.e xl I'm assuming should be x1. I changed all xl to x1 however there are still some issues. Your script has used the first two file paths to create a DF but it then does not loop through the remaining 273 files in the list.

Answer (score 0):

`My intended output would be a large dataframe, reading each file in the file path as a dataframe and binding them together.`

Depending on where the files live in your directory:

```r
library(readr)
library(dplyr)

files <- dir("data/", pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

df2_list <- vector("list", length(files))

names(df2_list) <- files

for (fname in files) {
  df2_list[[fname]] <- read_csv(fname)
}

df2 <- bind_rows(df2_list)
```

Then something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% summarise_each(funs(na.omit(.)))
```

This solution combines 3 separate `.csv` files with varying number of columns on my machine all located in the `data` folder within my working directory.

`df2 %>% summarise_each(funs(na.omit(.)))` accounts for the `NA`s generated from the joining.